# apache nifi: 'Execution node' is invalid because processors with incoming connections cannot be scheduled for primary node only

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a processor in nifi flow. It is based on [FetchFile](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.9.2/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.FetchFile/index.html).

On scheduling tab, it has Execution set as 'Primary Node'.

When I run this template with nifi 1.10.0, it has no issues. But with 1.22.0, I see error:

[image]

Please note that processor is build on 1.10.0 nar(I copied some of the 1.10.0 nars into lib folder of my 1.22.0 installation).

Is this something new introduced after 1.10.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be [NIFI-9825](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-9825) but since you have an incoming connection, the upstream "source" processor should be set to `Primary Node Only` and your `FetchXMLFile` processor should be configured to run on all nodes. Since the source processor runs on a single node, only those downstream processors on that node will get the FlowFile(s). If you want your `FetchXMLFile` instances to work in parallel, you can set up the incoming connection to use Load Balancing across the cluster.